# How to submit form without reloading the page using Spring Boot Async?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, asynchronous

I can do it with Ajax when submitting the form and passing it through JQuery.
I wonder if there's any alternative using Spring Boot @Async?

Here's my code so far, and as you can see the Post Request still returns a new ModelAndView page.

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public @Valid ModelAndView forPageScreen(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{   
    ModelAndView users = new ModelAndView("Practice");
    return users;
}


@Async
@Transactional
@PostMapping("/register")
public @Valid CompletableFuture<ModelAndView> addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("Practice");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        userRep.save(user);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(mav);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying your want the page to be reloaded automatically?  If so you have put jquery in your tag so you could use setinterval  to call a function that calls an ajax call

Comment: Don't be rude to people who are trying to help you. It's not cool and it's against the site's [CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Hi, I don't mean to make an offense to anyone who's especially trying to help me. It's highly appreciated to be honest, it's just that English is not my native language, so I'm not entirely familiar if I am being rude or sounding rash. I am very sorry for the matter if I've said any harsh words to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Async` is for server side Async, not for the AJAX. That's whole different use-case

> I can do it with Ajax when submitting the form and passing it through
>   JQuery

That's the way to go. Async should be handled at the client side (JQuery in this case). As far as the server is concerned, there is nothing Async about that httpRequest (In this scenario)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will continue to do so using AJAX, after all. Can you give me a scenario wherein @Async in server side would be useful?

Comment: @Async usage example: Let's say you want to make 2 time-consuming SQL queries, you can fire off both the queries parallel (instead of waiting for one to complete before firing another)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things to me. I've really thought `@Async` could also handle the client side because it's intended to be asynchronous. Clearly, I am wrong and very grateful to you. I've been working in this for days and trying to figure out if `@Async` could do the job.

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for letting me know.